# Translating DECODE in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

How can I translate the DECODE expression in Postgres?

```
MAX(DECODE(r.name,'AREA_SEC_TRANVERSAL',r.value,NULL)) AREA
```

I found the following type, but i did not know how "MAX" can fit in this case.

```
CASE search-expression
    WHEN expression [, expression [ ... ]] THEN
      statements
  [ WHEN expression [, expression [ ... ]] THEN
      statements
    ... ]
  [ ELSE
      statements ]
END CASE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common translation would use `case` a expression:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN r.name = 'AREA_SEC_TRANVERSAL' THEN r.value END) as AREA
```

In fact, the general replacement for `DECODE()` is `CASE`, which is the SQL standard for conditional logic -- I would recommend `CASE` even in databases that support `DECODE()`.

However, Postgres supports the **standard** SQL `filter` operator.  I would recommend using this instead:

```
MAX(r.value) FILTER (WHERE r.name = 'AREA_SEC_TRANVERSAL') as AREA
```

I find this easier to follow (perhaps now that I'm used to it).  More importantly, it gives the optimizer better options for improving performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can just keep max as is:

```
MAX(CASE 
      WHEN r.name = 'AREA_SEC_TRANVERSAL'
      THEN r.value
    END) AREA
```

or

```
MAX(CASE r.name 
      WHEN 'AREA_SEC_TRANVERSAL'
      THEN r.value
      ELSE null
    END) AREA
```